# Inserting formatted XML to a freemarker template

Tags: xml, freemarker

I'm new to freemarker and I wanted to know how to insert a field into freemarker but not have each new line indent from the beginning of the file but from the indentation of the root element.

For example I have a field

```
<Result>        
    ${response}
</Result>
```

This field is xml as a string with formatting. This has multiple lines. The first line is indented 1 tab as show by the ${response} variable. The 2nd line has it's indentation start not from 1 tab in but from the origin of the next line.

Example output

```
<Result>
    <Response>
<response-1>
    <response-1-child />
</response-1>
</Response>
</Result>
```

Where what I need is all the indentation to be done from the level that I have placed the variable.

```
 <Result>
     <Response>
         <response-1>
             <response-1-child />
         </response-1>
     <Response>
 </Result>
```

Any help would be appreciated. The responses are dynamic and could be of any length or size.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker can't help there. You will have to use a filter that re-formats the XML output as the output `Writer`. If what library should you use for that, I'm not sure, but surely FreeMarker has no such filter out-of-the-box.